# Python unable to read enviornment variables within Docker container

Tags: python, docker, cron

I am trying to set an environment variable for a container that is readable from my python script.

The python script is run via a containerized cron job. When running the script directly in the container, without the cronjob, I am able to read my environment variables.

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# install crontab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install -qq cron

# install crontab
ENV TESTING=1

ENV CONTAINER_HOME=/opt/
WORKDIR $CONTAINER_HOME

ADD runner.py .

COPY test-cron /etc/cron.d/test-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/test-cron

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/test-cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

The cron job that runs the script

```
# every 1 minutes 
* * * * * cd /opt/ && /usr/local/bin/python runner.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```

Lastly the script that is run

```
import os

print(os.environ)
```

I have also created a minimal example here: https://github.com/AndrewRPorter/python-docker-env.

Comment: Cron might empty the environment. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables for a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me

Comment: I was able to read the variable by exporting the variable in my cron command: `* * * * * export TESTING=1 && cd /opt/ && /usr/local/bin/python runner.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
`. This is not the desired solution though as I wish to keep the same cron job for both testing and production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is this to add in you Dockerfile something like this:

```
# install crontab
ENV TESTING=1

RUN echo "export TESTING=$TESTING" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

And...

`* * * * * . $HOME/.bashrc; cd /opt/ && /usr/local/bin/python runner.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1`

The dot before the $HOME is important.

Comment: Actually you can't use `source` (reliably and portably); `cron` uses `sh`, not `bash`; see also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)